# Regular Expression to Find a String but not in quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to Regular expressions I am looking a way to check a string contains a match but the match shouldn't be in single or double quotes.

```
ex:
var match = 'gs.info';

var example1 = 'var test=1; gs.info(test);'; // True

var example2 = 'var test="gs.info(test); blah blah"'; // false because it is in double quotes

var example3 = "var test='gs.info(test); blah blah'"; // false because it is in single quotes
```

Comment: I'd probably use lookarounds in this situation. `var match = "(?<!['"])gs.info(?!['"])"` `(?<!['"])` means "not preceeded by a single or double quote" and `(?!['"])` means "not followed by a single or double quote."

Comment: @brittenb which would fails for `some "random" test`

Comment: @brittenb javascript doesn't support look behind in regex

Comment: You could use a better regex engine which supports `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`, e.g. PCRE.

Comment: @Raulucco Thanks for the heads up; I wasn't aware that it didn't support that. That's good information to have.

Answer (score 0):

This example works:

```
var regex = /^(\.*(["'][\d\w\s]+["'])?[^"\'])*gs\.info(\(["']*[^)"']*["']*\))(\.*(["'][\d\w\s]+["'])?[^"\'])*$/g;
regex.test('var test="gs.info(test); blah blah"');
regex.test('var test=\'gs.info(test); blah blah\'');
```

The regex mean is:
`^[^"']*`: Anything that is not a double or single quotes at the beginning of the line and is repeated one o zero times,
`[^"']*$`: Anything that is not a double or single quotes till the end of the line that is repeated once or zero times.

Don't forget to escape the dot because this character has special meaning inside regular expressions.

Comment: thanks for the solution, it partially solving the problem. In the following scenario it is returning false `regex.test("gs.info('test'); ")`

Comment: `regex.test("var test='1'; gs.info(test); ");`

Comment: some reason it still not working for scenario `regex.test("gs.info('test'); ");`
`regex.test("var test='1'; gs.info(test);"); //False Not working`

Comment: @Kesav [look at this one](http://regexr.com/3cnpe) if this works for all your cases.